# Java 8 file I/O NoSuchElementException: no line found

Tags: java, string, io, java.util.scanner, printwriter

My goal is to read and write formatted strings to a file.
I'm actually using PrintWriter class for output and Scanner for input.

Code:

```
        PrintWriter out = null;
        Scanner in = null;
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/data/level1/grounds.txt");
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        out.println("foo");

        try {
            in = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        System.out.println(in.nextLine());
        in.close();
```

The file is created, but in.nextLine() throws a *NoSuchElementException: no line found*.
After the execution (terminated by this exception) the file is blank.

Please leave a suggestion about how to do it correctly.

Comment: As an aside, you are in Java 8, you really should avoid using `File` and switch to using `Path` and all the related methods in the `java.nio` package. Also, you shouldn't output to the file if the file wasn't found. The print should be inside the `try`. And you should use "try-with-resources" to auto-close the file when you're done with it.

Answer (score 1):

You should close the output printer once you are done with all writing to make it reflect in Scanner.

Comment: Oh, i missed such an obvious thing. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `out.println("foo");` writes in the `PrintWriter` but not on the file, you need to `flush()` to have the content on the file, you may `close()` also (this will automatically `flush()`

1. Simple flush

   ```
   out.println("foo"); 
   out.flush()
   ```
2. Close to flush

   ```
   out.println("foo"); 
   out.close()
   ```
3. Use an auto-flush PrintWriter

   ```
   out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), true);
   ```